# iTerm 2 Profiles/Bookmarks

Tags: macos, ssh, iterm

I know this is supposed to be really simple but for the life of me I can't figure out how to store all of the URL's that I typically log into on the [iTerm 2](http://www.iterm2.com/) Profiles page.  I come from a PuTTY background where once you open the program, the very first screen allows you to just type in the Host Name/IP Address and a Name for the session and you click Save and that's it.  And I could also set the Private key for authentication under SSH->Auth.

Yet these simple features are either non-existant or extremely hidden because I can't seem to find them anywhere in the Preferences.

Comment: On unix-y systems like OS X, it's more common to store ssh login profiles in `~/.ssh/config`.  Then you can just type `ssh host1` in a shell or, if necessary, add that as the `command` associated with an iTerm 2 profile.

Comment: So does that mean it's not possible at all using the GUI?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Profiles / Open Profiles / Edit Profiles Button and select + (at Botton)

Create a profile to each ssh host, and put the address selecting Command  command and add command ssh user@host.xxx (or ip)

If do you like sort all entries, add tags to create structure sorted.
And you can add badge to add background text at windows, ie: Prod or Test

To view this bookmarks you can select Toolbet / Show Toolbet

If you like remember the password can use Window / Password Manager and create different passwords...

When you select the profile and ask to password click at key icon and show at popup window showing you passwords saved and you select the correct line and continue without ask password.